# Why there is event passed as parameter in jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was revising some concept in jquery then I found a simple code which I understood properly but there is "event" passed in that function and I didn't understand why is it passed because we could achieve that functionality without it.

```
var hiddenBox = $( "#banner-message" );
$( "#button-container button" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
  hiddenBox.show();
});
```

In above code I want to know why event is passed in this function? Also what better we can do with this. If possible please also provide an example.

Thanks

Comment: Sometimes the parameter is essential, eg `event.preventDefault()`. If you don't use `event`, feel free to leave out the parameter

Comment: Yes I understand But I also want to know what this event is refering to? 
I mean is it refering to  "#button-container button" or onClick event.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

Comment: This is not specific about jQuery, see the native `addEventListener` handler function as a reference, it also has the same parameter.